# Converting C++ #Define enum creation to vb.net

Tags: c++, vb.net, enums

For a project i need to a Enum list writen in C++ converterd to en VB.net Enum list. So far everything is OK except for the #define enums that are in the C++ list. Here's what i whant to convert:

```
typedef enum
{
 #define EnumValue(a,b) a, b=a+255
 EnumValue(PARAM_Start,PARAM_END)
} ID;
```

As you can see this creates 255 enums values at runtime. How is this done in VB.net?

**EDIT / SOLVED 30-09-2016** 
As mentioned below i made the wrong assumption by thinking it would create 255 enums, instead it creates just two enums however given `PARAM_END` an extra offset of 255. Meaning: if i have a three enums, the index of these enums are 0,1,3. Now if i want the index of `ENUM_3` to begin at 10 i just add `ENUM_2 + 8` this way ENUM_3 will start at index 10.

Thanks all for responding so fast and helping me out! :-)

Comment: It actually only creates 2, PARAM_Start and PARAM_END, of value 0 and 255 respectively.

Comment: There is no `#define` equivalent in VB .NET.

Comment: @AlexB.: There are equivalents to simple #define constants, but not #define macros.

Comment: Dear Reza Aghaei, thanks for pointing this out. I'm still new here (read allot) i will keep it in mind for my next post :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VB equivalent is:

```
Public Enum ID
 PARAM_Start
 PARAM_END=PARAM_Start+255
End Enum
```

Not 255 values as you stated, but just 2.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, I think your C++ will create only 2...

Could you use a [T4 Text Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)?:

Add `TextTemplate.tt` to your VB project and fill it with this code:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ output extension=".vb" #>

Namespace MyNamespace

    Public Enum MyEnum
    <# 
    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
    {
    #>
    Number<#= i #> = <#= i #>
    <# } #>
    End Enum

End Namespace
```

Build your solution and it'll generate the type for you.

Comment: @ Gill Bates, i think you're right. Didn't notice it. Still i don't quite understand wat the meaning/goal is? Is it to declare a enum with two subvalues that can be 0 to 255? @ Brandon, Thanks for the snippet, i will read the MSDN doc and try it.

Comment: The link is only there for reference. You can just copy the code into a `.tt` file and build your solution.